# replacing value in new dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have dataframe like below picture df

what i need is to replace the value of WoE columns in new data frame
for example like column class there is A whenever A come replace it with -0.555067

```
class_woe={'A':-0.555067,
                       'B:-0.411769,
                       'C':-0.032279,
                       'D:0.590863,
                       'E':0.640516
} 

train['Clss_WOE'] = train.class.map(class_woe).apply(pd.to_numeric).astype(float)
```

[image]

here is expected output
[image]

Comment: can you show your expected output

Comment: @AzizAlreshidi Can you please edit your question and put the expected output there (with correct formatting)?

Comment: Please provide more clarity. Your expected output is pretty confusing and having more records than the given one.

Comment: I add the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Though, there are many ways to solve this , I would use numpy 'where' to do this job as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],'Count': [15698, 14304, 61570, 8546,13519],'WoE':[-0.56670,0.411769,-0.032279,0.590863,0.640516]})
df['WoE'] = np.where((df.Class == 'A'),-0.555067,df.WoE)
```

good part about numpy where is you can pass multiple conditions and loops and it does wonders.